# need different default git user, depending on the project

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

For both my personal and my work I use the same computer, but two different github account : A pro account, who is imposed by my current company and will be closed when I leave it, and a personal account who is mine.

The commit I do for my work are done by my pro account, but
I do a lot of open-source, and I wish the commits on the opensource would be done by default by my personal account. (potential recruters will only see the work of my personal account)

**How can I easily switch from a default account to another when I commit my code? I don't want to specify manualy the account in each commit**

All the projects are on the same computer, but in differents workspace repositories. There are no projects on which I should both do commit with my personal account and my pro account.

I use Intellij Idea , and most of the time  Iuse it IHM to do the commits (I don't do my commit in command line)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+users